# Null Reference Exception Run Time Error

Tags: vb.net, nullreferenceexception

Hi all im getting a null reference run time error with one line of code in my project, however if i break point it and then step through it everything works fine. Any Thoughts

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim checkbox_l As String = "CheckBox"
    Dim checkbox_i As string
    For i As Integer = 1 To id Step 1
        checkbox_i = checkbox_l + i.ToString
        Try
            If CType(Panel1.Controls(checkbox_i), CheckBox).Checked = True Then
                My.Settings.name = Panel1.Controls("CheckBox" & i).Text
                Call installer_properties()
                Call start_install()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    Next
End Sub
```

The code is meant to check if a dynamically created checkbox has been checked and then move on accordingly, however im getting an error with the line

```
If CType(Panel1.Controls(checkbox_i), CheckBox).Checked = True Then
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Debug.Assert to catch it

```
Dim c as Control = Panel1.Controls(checkbox_i)
Debug.Assert(c IsNot Nothing)
Dim cb as CheckBox = TryCast(c, CheckBox)
If cb isNot Nothing Then
   If cb.Checked = True Then
      My.Settings.name = cb.Text
      Call installer_properties()
      Call start_install()
   End If
End If
```

Comment: thanks ive been trying to figure that out for the last two weeks without any joy, now i can finally move on to the last part of the application and maybe have it ready for my client within the next week or so. again thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To get result 1 if checked and 0 - if not, you can write down:

textbox1.text = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(Panel1.Controls("CheckBox" & i).ToString, 1)